# org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I got this exception:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: 
>       Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException:
>       Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]

When i am using
`session = sessionFactory.openSession();` for `session` .

And i got

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

When i am using `session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` for `session`.

what should i do?

**UPDATE**

Here is `persistUser()`in `UserServiceImpl` class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService<User, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
@Transactional()
public boolean persistUser(User entity) {
    boolean result;
    userDao.openSessionWithTransaction();
    result = userDao.persist(entity);
    userDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    return result;
}
...
}
```

And here is `userDaoImpl`:

```
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao<User, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session session;
private Transaction transaction;

@Override
public Session openSessionWithTransaction() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    return session;
}

@Override
public void closeSessionWithTransaction() {
    getTransaction().commit();
    sessionFactory.close();
}

@Override
public boolean persist(User entity) {
    if (session.save(entity).getClass().getName() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported` implies that you may have more than one active transaction somewhere in the code you wrote which you cannot have. Perhaps, your method already uses an active transaction where you might be attempting to create another transaction which was forbidden throwing the mentioned exception. Make it a proper transactional unit.

Comment: Also your first exception is typical for the case when you're opening a closed session. You should add some code for further hepl, but as general comment let the Spring  handle your transactions

Comment: @MasterSlave I added more details in `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you don't need any of the transaction related methods in your DAO, in fact, they are causing your issues. Lean on the Springs declarative transaction handling, and change your service to

```
@Override
@Transactional()
public boolean persistUser(User entity) {
    boolean result;
    result = userDao.persist(entity);
    return result;
}
```

This way, your service method will be used for transaction demarcation, meaning the transaction will start when your method is called , and commit when your method ends (or rollback if there's an exception). Everything inside the method will be in a single transaction, no need for programmatic transaction handling

Comment: Thanks, Now i am getting `javax.faces.FacesException: #{userBean.registeration()}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: ok, but this is a complete separate issue, better post it as a separate question, you'll also benefit from appropriate tags as this issue is JSF related

Comment: Well.. maybe *you* can help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694247/unknownserviceexception-unknown-service-requested-hibernate-spring