# UnknownServiceException from hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 4 to set up my stuff that I'll need for using Hibernate 4.  I have a `SessionFactory` autowired into my DAO layer.  When I call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "MyImporterThread" org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException:  Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

I've looked at many search results from Google (including a bunch from StackOverflow) on this exception, however none of them has struck me as the solution to my issue.

Here's my configuration:

spring-beans.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:spring.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.scraping" />

<!-- Data Source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver.class}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.scraping" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>file:scraping.db.hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Stuff -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- beans that are transactional or autowired -->
<bean id="scrapingDao" class="com.company.scraping.dao.ReportsScrapingDaoImpl" />
<bean id="scrapingService" class="com.company.scraping.service.ReportsScrapingServiceImpl" />
```

spring.properties:

```
jdbc.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:testdb01
jdbc.user=user
jdbc.password=password
```

scraping.db.hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:testdb01</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Since this is not a web application, I use `ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0])` to initialize Spring.

My service class is autowired (not shown in the config because I have to type all this out), and contains an autowired instance of the DAO.  This is what the DAO looks like:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public class ReportsScrapingDaoImpl implements ReportsScrapingDao 
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transaction(readOnly = true)
    public List<Stuff> getAll()
    {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Stuff.class);
        ... (more code)
    }
}
```

The code bombs out when `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is called.  I've tried using `sessionFactory.openSession()` as well, but it gave the same results.  I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a last-ditch search and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694247/unknownserviceexception-unknown-service-requested-hibernate-spring) turned up.  Eclipse outputs a compiler warning, complaining that there may be a resource leak because the `ApplicationContext` is never closed.  I added a line at the very end of my `main` method (after all the `Threads` had been started) to close the `ApplicationContext`.  Once I got rid of the line that closes the `ApplicationContext`, the problem went away.

Moral of the story is that your `ApplicationContext` should not be closed until you no longer need anything from it--so you should probably never close it.